# AngularJS app not loading when using angulartics for Piwik

Tags: javascript, angularjs, matomo

I'm trying to use this: http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics and running into some issues. I am not able to debug it and I am not finding any info about it anywhere.

In **app.js**, I am adding the Angularitics dependencies (to my existing ones):

```
var app = angular.module('shiftSwap', [
                         'ui.router'
                       , 'infinite-scroll'
                       , 'angulartics'
                       , 'angulartics.piwik'
                       ]);
```

In my **index.html**, I have:

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angulartics-piwik.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

When I load the app, I get the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-
beta.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=shiftSwap&p1….angularjs.org%2F1.3.0-
beta.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dangulartics%...<omitted>...7)
```

This error links to this page, which gives me no information. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=shiftSwap&p1=undefined.

Would anyone have any idea of what may be happening?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see in [Angulartics repository](https://github.com/luisfarzati/angulartics/tree/master/dist) that there are the following files:

- angulartics.min.js
- angulartics-piwik.min.js
- angulartics-ga.min.js
- angulartics-....min.js

So maybe did you forget to include `angulartics.min.js`? It doesn't appear in the index.html you posted above.

Comment: Duh. Thank you!!!! Somehow missed including [this file](https://github.com/luisfarzati/angulartics/blob/master/src/angulartics.js).